# cannot get menubar to work in IE

Tags: html, css

This menubar is working in Chrome and Firefox but does not appear in IE. I have tried different versions of IE and does not appear with any of them.

```
 <div id="menubar">
        <ul id="menu">
          <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="positions.html">Positions</a></li>
          <li><a href="pandp.html">Policy &amp; Procedure</a></li>
          <li><a href="guides.html">Guides & Links</a></li>
          <li><a href="forms.html">Forms</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--close menubar-->

#menubar
{ width: 920px;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 0 0 20px;
  height: 30px;}
```

Comment: Im able to see the menu on IE. Can you upload the entire page or exclude the CSS from your html and confirm that the menu is there?

Comment: I just tried that code and it works as far as I can see. What do you mean by it does not appear?

Comment: When I open in Chrom/Firefox the menu is there. When I open in IE the menu is not there.

Comment: it's IE compatibility settings, can't get them to stick.

Answer (score 0):

Well... you have just a list. Did you try using the `<menu>` and `<menuitem>` tags?

```css
#menubar
{ width: 920px;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 0 0 20px;
  height: 30px;}
```

```html
<div id="menubar">
        <menu id="menu">
          <menuitem class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></menuitem>
          <menuitem><a href="news.html">News</a></menuitem>
          <menuitem><a href="positions.html">Positions</a></menuitem>
          <menuitem><a href="pandp.html">Policy &amp; Procedure</a></menuitem>
          <menuitem><a href="guides.html">Guides & Links</a></menuitem>
          <menuitem><a href="forms.html">Forms</a></menuitem>
        </menu>
      </div><!--close menubar-->
```

### EDIT

I can see the menu on IE too (IE11) not as menu, but as unordered list.